# How can I port C++ code that uses the ternary operator to Rust?

Tags: if-statement, rust, conditional-operator

How can I port this C++ code to Rust:

```
auto sgnR = (R >= 0.) ? 1. : -1.;
```

I have seen some examples with the `match` keyword, but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1362

Comment: Google "rust ternary operator" and you'll find a bunch of hits.

Comment: @Baum This question requires understanding of both Rust and C++ so it is one of the very few questions that should have both tags. I do, however, think it should be closed for *other* reasons.

Comment: @Galik Nah, tags are for finding relevant stuff. No one with a C++ question will want to find this question, so it should not have the tag. It's not a C++ question, but solely a rust question. (Also, I don't get the "it should be closed for *other* reasons" part, that appears to pretty orthogonal to the whole tagging issue.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen But how do you expect a pure Rust programmer to convert code from a language he doesn't understand? Some knowledge of C++ is required. If people don't want to find this question then it should rather be closed than mistagged

Comment: @Galik *"But how do you expect a pure Rust programmer to convert code from a language he doesn't understand?"* I don't expect people who don't know this syntax to answer this question at all, but that does not make this a question about C++. *"If people don't want to find this question then it should rather be closed than mistagged"* People looking for *C++* answers won't want to find it. People looking of Rust answer probably will. Thus it should be tagged [rust], but not [c++].

Comment: i just wanted to say that... coming from C/C++, the "match" statement is like a "super ternary" operator.... in that the ternary operator only allows to check a boolean to continue to one of two values... with match you can check a pattern against an input, and continue to many many different values.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Rust does not have the ternary operator because it's not needed. Almost everything evaluates to some value, and `if` / `else` expressions are no exception:

```
let r = 42.42;
let sgn_r = if r >= 0. { 1. } else { -1. };
```

You'll note that I've also changed your variable names to be idiomatic Rust. Identifiers use `snake_case`.

Do not be confused by the `?` operator that Rust *does* have. This is [called the "try operator" and is used to propagate errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator).

---

Specifically for *this* code, it's likely you should use [`f64::signum`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.signum):

```
let r = 42.42_f64;
let sgn_r = r.signum();
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`bool::then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then) or in this case, the non-lazy [`bool::then_some`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then_some) to accomplish the same thing:

```rust
let sgn_r = (r >= 0).then_some(1).unwrap_or(-1);
```

An `if/else` statement is probably better for readability, but this may be nicer in certain cases.

Answer (score 1):

I like to implement a similar construct using a trait:

```rust
pub trait IfElse {
    fn ifelse<T>(&self, iftrue: T, iffalse: T) -> T;
}

impl IfElse for bool {
    fn ifelse<T>(&self, iftrue: T, iffalse: T) -> T {
        if *self { iftrue }
        else { iffalse }
    }
}
```

Then it can be used like this:

```rust
let sng_r = (r >= 0).ifelse(1, -1);
```