# How do I convert a boolean to an integer in Rust?

Tags: rust

How do I convert a boolean to an integer in Rust? As in, `true` becomes 1, and `false` becomes 0.

Comment: @Stargateur I was printing them to the screen for debugging, and printing out 1s and 0s was more handy in my case than `true` and `false`.

Comment: Sometimes useful in arithmetic e.g.
`pub fn calculateprice(num : i32) -> i32 { return ((num > 40) as i32 * num) + num; }`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Cast it:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", true as i32)
}
```

Comment: Works, but this is too C++. Even Java would complain about this, and Rust should too, in my opinion.

Comment: @ChrisVilches why?

Comment: @Newbyte A `true` is a `1` only from a hardware point of view (and we can only assume non-exotic hardware), but not from a conceptual point of view. Which is fine, since it's a valid way to model it. In Java, `1` and `true` are two different concepts.

Comment: @ChrisVilches a bool having a value other than 0 or 1 is considered undefined behaviour: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html

Answer (score 37):

A boolean value in Rust is [guaranteed to be `1` or `0`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html):

> The `bool` represents a value, which could only be either `true` or `false`. If you cast a `bool` into an integer, `true` will be 1 and `false` will be 0.

A boolean value, which is **neither** `0` **nor** `1` is [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html):

> A value other than `false` (`0`) or `true` (`1`) in a bool.

Therefore, you can just cast it to a primitive:

```
assert_eq!(0, false as i32);
assert_eq!(1, true as i32);
```

Answer (score 22):

Use an `if` statement:

```
if some_boolean { 1 } else { 0 }
```

See also:

- [How can I port C++ code that uses the ternary operator to Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45092638/155423)

Comment: A [simple benchmark](https://github.com/ssomers/rust_bench_quickies/tree/master/src) shows that this is 20% faster than the other answers.

Comment: @Stein I think your link is outdated.

Comment: @Stein Current nightly appears to generate identical code for `is_some_as` and `is_some_if`: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/edcKef.

Comment: @SolomonUcko Not quite, it seems. The benchmarks still report the same difference today (regardless of names and place in file, which could influence alignment). When I swap the `-O` in your very useful godbolt link with the `-C opt-level=3` that `cargo bench` feeds, it does report a difference in assembly.

Comment: Hmm, true, interesting! Here's a smaller example: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/7MM49d. I'm not completely sure what's up with the control flow for `is_some_if`.

Comment: [Rust issue #95522](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95522) (possibly an LLVM issue) suggests this is not the best way to write it, in the rare case performance matters extremely. Contrary to that, the option_cardinality part of [a simple microbenchmark](https://github.com/ssomers/rust_bench_quickies) suggests it is faster, with most Rust builds, but I believe that benchmark misrepresents bool-to-integer conversion because it basically checks `if pointer != null { 1 } else { 0 }`, which should branch anyway.

Answer (score 13):

You may use `.into()`:

```
let a = true;
let b: i32 = a.into();
println!("{}", b); // 1

let z: isize = false.into();
println!("{}", z); // 0
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3297f5b00842ef949369a613e0775911)