# Rust: Why would the compiler translate !!value as value?

Tags: rust

Could someone clarify why using `NOT` operator twice like in the following example:

```rs
setBits += !!(n & mask); // if some bits match between n and mask, setBits = 1, else setBits = 0
```

Which basically works in C language, and also work after I had rewritten it this way:

```rs
setBits += if (n & mask) != 0 {1} else {0};
```

Does not work as intended in Rust? As of now, it returns the value of n & mask, while I want to force twice NOT at the bytecode level and **avoid branching** (`cmp` instructions).

**NB: I just checked the assembly code and apparently the Rust compiler optimize it away...

However `!!value` is not equivalent to `value`**

Any way to force `NOT x2` and avoid `CMP` instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust's [`Not`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Not.html) operator (`!`) does not return `bool` but rather the *bitwise negation* of the value. It is more akin to C/C++'s bitwise not operator (`~`):

```
let bits = 0u32;
println!("{:#010X}", bits);
println!("{:#010X}", !bits);
```

```
0x00000000
0xFFFFFFFF
```

So this is why `!!` would typically not do anything.

You can still do this without an `if` by [converting the `bool` from `!= 0` into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461617/how-do-i-convert-a-boolean-to-an-integer-in-rust):

```
setBits += (n & mask != 0) as u32; // assuming u32s
```

Comment: You beat me by 5 seconds, and provide a better answer to boot. :)

Comment: I was testing locally and just found out that as well that not is equivalent to ~ neg. It is very confusing, I don't understand the design choice to use `!` instead of `~` for `NEG`, especially if Rust is looking to attract C and C++ developers. Anyways there is no way, in Rust, to call `NOT`?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Which `NOT` instruction are you referring to? [The x86 one does what Rust does, not what C does.](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/not)

Comment: The C and C++ one

Comment: Yes, it's spelled `x == 0`

Comment: I would call `!` for integers in Rust a _bitwise NOT_ rather than _logical NOT_. It's logical NOT for Boolean values, but bitwise NOT for integers.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I'm inclined to agree with you. I rewrote the wording a couple times because *negation* would be `-x` and also felt *bitwise negation* is more appropriate to what its doing, but the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Not.html) call it the "unary logical negation operator" so idk what to think.

Comment: FWIW [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) calls it a "bitwise or logical complement" (logical presumably to cover `bool` where "bitwise complement" might be imprecise), which sounds reasonable. Maybe the trait docs should be updated to use that term?

Comment: IIRC, on LLVM IR level rust bools are 1 bit unsigned integers, so it is still bitwise, at least in theory.